# Function with one specified parameter and the rest optional

Tags: javascript, typescript

what is the correct way to specify a function type that has exactly one parameter of a specified type and an arbitrary amount of optional other parameters ?

The best i found would be something like this:

```
function fun(x: string, ...rest: any[]);
```

Is there a better way to achieve what i want ?

Comment: Are you talking about a `declaration` or an `assertion`? Do you need to specify, somewhere, that a specific function has a specific amount of parameters or do you need to **declare** a function with such? In your example, you're **declaring** a function, specifying the first argument type and defining N additional arguments. This is the correct approach, for your use case, hence I'm not exactly understanding what is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
function fun(x: string, options: Object) {
    ...
}
```